# Присоединение ОДНОГО поля из другой Entity

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-data

Я реализую RESTFul сервис, позволяющий возвращать информацию о пользователях. У меня есть два Entity, которые цепляются из БД.

Первая сущность, описывающая пользователя, берется из таблицы **User** и выглядит следующим образом:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "code")
    Long id;
    Long pos;
    Long sapid;
    String username;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String middleName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "code",  insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Point point;
}
```

Следующая сущность описывает отделение, в котором работает указанный пользователь, берется из таблицы **Point**:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Point {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "code")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String location;

    String zip;
    String regionCode;
    String city;
    String street;
    String house;
    String info;
}
```

Моей задачей является возврат JSON-а следующего содержания:

```
{
“id”:2356,
“user”:”user”,
“location”:”отделение1”    
}
```

Начав реализовывать DTO для возврата JSON я столкнулся с проблемой: при реализованной мной связи в Entity **User** в поле Point записывается целая привязанная сущность.

```
{
  "id": 41,
  "user": "user",
  "point": {
    "zip": "zip",
    "location" : "location1"
    "regionCode": "123",
    "city": "city",
    "street": "str",
    "house": "h2",
    "info": "some info"
  }
}
```

**Вопрос**: Как я должен преобразовывать сущность в процессе маппинга в дто, чтобы получить JSON требуемого мне формата? (цеплять из point только location, а не полную информацию о отделении). Хотелось бы избегать нативных SQL запросов и работать именно с объектным представлением, спасибо.

Comment: Если я правильно понял Вы хотите вытянуть только поле `location` из сущности `Point`. Тогда можете воспользоватся `EntityGraph`-ми: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm#BABCJBCG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой метод с префиксом get будет обработан сериалайзером

```
class DTO{
    // сам поинт скрыт
    @JsonIgnore
    private Point point;

    // будто бы такое поле существует
    String getLocation(){
       return point.getLocation();
    }
...
}
```

А вообще, не передавайте сущности целиком в ДТО, если не хотите видетьполное содержание. Если вы хотите видеть там три поля, то создавай ДТо ровно с тремя полями

```
    class DTO{
        private Long id;
        private String user;
        private String location;
    ...
    }

dto.setId(42);
dto.setUser("user");
dto.setLocation("Some location");
```